# Generic in abstract and static context

Tags: java, generics

I have different subclasses of abstract class A which all should implement a getInstance Method. The method checks if an instance is already saved on disc in xml format ([XStream library](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html)) and loads it or creates a new instance.

```
public MySubclassB extends A {   

...

private static SettingsManager<MySubclassB> manager;
private static MySubclassB instance;

private MySubclassB() {
    manager = new SettingsManager<MySubclassB>();
}

public static MySubclassB getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {

        MySubclassB tmp = new MySubclassB();

        // loadObject returns either tmp if no instance was saved on disc or the saved object
        if ((instance = manager.loadObject(tmp, MySubclassB.class.getCanonicalName())).hashCode() == tmp.hashCode()) {
            setUpObjectFirstTime();
        } 
    }
    return instance;
}
}
```

Is it possible to do all of this in the abstract Class A or should i duplicate the code in all subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to duplicate the code as type parameters are relevant to instances only and so can't be used in static fields or methods.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createStatic